# Cant use dll FreeImage

Tags: c#, image, dll

plz can you help me with dll Freeimage. Im decide to use this library for compressing images. I was add it by NuGet service:
[Nuget with FreeImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqZX4.png)

then i add library in css file

```
using FreeImageAPI;
 FIBITMAP dib = FreeImage.LoadEx(imageName);
        // Check success
        if (dib.IsNull)
        {
            Response.Write("Could not load Sample.jpg");
        }  
        // Convert Bitmap to JPEG2000 and save it on the hard disk
        FreeImage.Save(FREE_IMAGE_FORMAT.FIF_JP2, dib, "Image.jp2", FREE_IMAGE_SAVE_FLAGS.EXR_PXR24 | FREE_IMAGE_SAVE_FLAGS.EXR_LC);
        // Unload source bitmap
        FreeImage.UnloadEx(ref dib);
        ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
        byte[] fdib = (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(dib, typeof(byte[]));
        string file_type = "application/jp2";
        string file_name = "Image.jp2";
        return File(fdib, file_type, file_name);
```

It built suceed, but when im try to execute method it give me error:
"An exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occured in FreeImageNET.dll but was not handled in user code

then i was read that need to add dll by references, but there also problem
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VymUY.png)

Please, help me.

Comment: At which line does this exception occur?

Comment: @Pavieł Kraskoŭski on this: `FIBITMAP dib = FreeImage.LoadEx(imageName);`

Comment: I think, that the file you want to pass to `LoadEx` method doesn't exist on your disk. So you have this exception. What is `imageName`?

Comment: @ Pavieł Kraskoŭski  thats byte array of image taken from datebase and converted to string
`ApplicationUser au = db.Users.Include(t => t.Pictures).FirstOrDefault(t => (t.Id) == user);
            Picture pic = au.Pictures.Where(p => p.Id == id).First();
            string imageName = Convert.ToBase64String(pic.Image);`

Comment: According to documentation (http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/fnet/Index.html), `LoadEx` method accepts a path of a specific file on your disk, not `Base64String`.

Comment: @ Pavieł Kraskoŭski thank you